# System error. The error has been logged and we will investigate

Tags: google-bigquery

I started getting this result from BigQuery around 5pm PST. I haven't changed anything in my app. I can still make queries via the online browser tool. Is this happening to anyone else? Our project ID is decent-surf-855.

Comment: Are you getting a HTTP error as well?  See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

Comment: I'm using the bigquery node module. I don't think I'm getting HTTP errors, but I haven't dug into the module yet.

I have found that some queries are working sometimes. The smaller and less complicated they are, the more likely it is that they will succeed. These are all queries that worked fine today prior to 5pm on the same datasets.

It sucks that thist started happening to us only after business hours.

Comment: _System error. The error has been logged and we will investigate_ It's clearly explained that it is an internal error so you simply have to wait, at most, communicate it to them, but it is though off-topic in SO

Comment: If you look at their support page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support it specifically links to StackOverflow to ask a question if you have a problem.  Which basically encourages people to post questions here that may be off-topic for SO.  Down the bottom of the page is a link where you can actually lodge a bug with them. http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: And yes, someone else is getting that error too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378028/1-system-error-the-error-has-been-logged-and-we-will-investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We changed the wording of the error message from the old "Unexpected. Please try again." Perhaps you already had code to detect or filter based on that error text?

Comment: Well it stopped happening. So I don't really know what to think about it.